True or False of the Cubic Newton Fractal ?: Each point of the Julia Set is a common boundary point of six disjoint "basin" components
Concerning the Cubic Newton Fractal, i.e. the Julia set, in the complex plane, for iterations of $z \mapsto z - (z^3 - 1) / (3 z^2)$,
I'd like to check a particular assertion which I have (perhaps mistakenly) always considered true and widely known,
but (to my surprise, when being challenged recently) have not found explicitly stated in "the literature", as far as I've been able to research. Namely
My question:
Is it true that each point of the Cubic Newton Fractal (Julia Set) is a common boundary point of six disjoint components ("basins of attraction") of the corresponding Fatou Set ?
When, and by whom, was this assertion (or its opposite) proved first; or, if not (yet) proved, then conjectured first ?

See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lakes_of_Wada#Wada_basins

For a possible proof, see the paper mentioned at https://math.stackexchange.com/a/122239/589

@lhf: "See also en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lakes_of_Wada#Wada_basin" -- Thanks, but my Q is specificly about the Cubic Newton Fractal and six disconnected/disjoint "basin components" of the corresponding Fatou Set. E.g. precisely those 6 -- 2 red, 2 green, 2 blue --  which apparently "meet" at point $(0,0)$. "For a possible proof, see" -- I woudln't be able to access https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet/relay-station?mr=2310015 for a few days; we have e.g. https://www.uni-konstanz.de/mmsp/pubsys/publishedFiles/PeSaHa84.pdf

Yes, this is a true statement, though I guess there are three basins in your example. It's an immediate consequence of the definition of the Julia and Fatou sets in terms of normal families and Montel's theorem.
More specifically, these definitions are taken from page 54 of Complex Dynamics by Carlson:

The Fatou set $F$ of a rational function $R$ is defined to be the set of points $z\in\mathbb C$ such that the family of iterated $\{R^n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is a normal family in some neighborhood of $z_0$. The Julia set $J$ is the complement of the Fatou set.

Thus, if $z_0 \in J$ and $U$ is an open set containing $U$, then $\{R^n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ cannot be a normal family on $U$.
We can now combine that with Montel's theorem, as stated on page 10 of the same text:

Let $\cal F$ be a family of meromorphic functions on a domain $D$. If there are three fixed values that are omitted by every $f\in F$, then $F$ is a normal family.

In particular,
$$\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} R^n(U)$$
contains all but three elements of the Riemann sphere. Since the basins of attraction are forward invariant, they all intersected $U$ in the first place.

Mark McClure: "[...] Though I guess there're 3 basins in your OP." -- Thanks for your careful answer, but:$~~$ I am asking about six disconnected "basin components"! Please look at the great standard picture: All red "basin patches" together are called one basin of attraction, in total, AFAIU. Likewise all green; all blue. So yes, by definition, each point of the (white) Julia Set is a common border point of these 3 basins-in-total. But each of those has infinite disjoint "basin components". How do you call those ??, btw.

Well, the unbounded red region to the right of the origin contains the ray $(0,\infty)$, the largest bounded red region to the left of the origin maps to the unbounded region, and similarly for the green and blue, which is why you've got six regions meeting at zero. Furthermore, the inverse images of the pole are dense in the Julia set. Maybe that's what you're looking for.

Mark McClure: "the largest bounded red region [...] maps to the unbounded [red] region" -- Thanks for using appropriate terminology (which I recognize, but hadn't been able to discern in "the literature" I skimmed). "[Thus] you've got six regions meeting at zero." -- Easy! But why isn't this (six) written down anywhere ?? Is it even true (as I suggested), at all ?: What about e.g. bounded red regions which "close in on" point $(0,0)$ along the Imaginary axis of $\mathbb C$ ? Are there perhaps twelve "basin regions meeting" at $(0,0)$ ? Please expand your answer accordingly! ...

Mark McClure: "Furthermore, the inverse images of the pole are dense in the Julia set." -- "The Pole" is terminology which appears neither here nor there nor there nor there in Wikipedia ! So, sorry, I cannot relate (yet) and so I fail to follow this particular argument. Again, I'd appreciate if you could make your answer more self-contained and/or linked in even more detail. Thanks again!

A pole is just what the Newton iteration function has at 0; for rational functions we can think of it as the point at infinity, which turns out to be an unstable fixed point for the iteration when we extend the function.
